# VBA: trying to compare values seemingly gives random results

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a supposedly simple function in VBA but am stuck. 
I have a value in a cell that can have any value from 0 to 100. With a simple "If" statement it is supposed to filter out values of or below 10 and values of 100. If a value is not filtered out, the entire row is copied to a different sheet.

Here's what I have:

```
For r = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Range("H" & r).value > "10" And Range("H" & r).value < "100" Then
    Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Funnel").Range("A" & LastRowDestination)
        LastRowDestination = LastRowDestination + 1
    End If
Next r
```

The comparison seems to only work in certain instances, however. It seems to work fine for this statement:

```
If Range("H" & r).value > "10" Then
```

The issue appears when I introduce the smaller than comparison. It will copy the correct rows (such as all with a value lower than 80, if I compared it to 80) but additionally it will copy rows that have a value of 100. The greater than statement still works as expected, filtering out the values that are too small.

With the following comparison though, no row is copied:

```
If Range("H" & r).value > "10" AND Range("H" & r).value < "100" Then
```

And with this comparison, rows that have a value of 0 or 10 get copied:

```
If Range("H" & r).value < "100" Then
```

There seems to be a pattern, but I cannot get behind why this is happening the way it is happening. Any suggestions to solve this is appreciated.

Comment: Try it without the quotation marks.

Comment: When you use the quotation marks, you're comparing the value of your cell with a string.  If you remove them, you're comparing the value of the cell with a number.  For < and > etc type operations, it's the number you'd want to use.

Comment: Well, that was dumb on my part. Thank you guys - problem solved!

Comment: @curzic I added an answer with examples for this issue (maybe you'll find it interesting)

Answer (score 1):

By using `"10"` instead of `10` you are comparing strings. This happens alphabetical, like in a dictionary. So for example

```
"1" < "2" < "20" < "3" < "34593045983049580" < "4"
```

It is a close call though because VBA will convert variables if you try to compare them. If you try to compare an number with a string, it tries to convert the string to a number:

```
?"2"<"10"
False

?2<"10"
True

?"2"<"a"
True

?2<"a"
*type mismatch*
```

As you can see it converts the string `"10"` to the integer `10` in the second example when it just as well could convert the `2` to `"2"`. I guess it makes sense because `<` is obviously more often used to compare numbers than strings.

In the last example, it tries to convert `"a"` to an integer which doesn't work so you get the error.

In your case, you compared the `Value` of a cell to a string so the outcome depends on if the `Value` is cast as a string or number. Apparently it decides that because you are comparing it to a string, you want it to be a string.

Here is a test sub:

```
Sub testStringComparison()
    Dim dbl As Double
    Dim str As String
    Dim var As Variant

    dbl = Cells(1, 1).Value 'Cell contains 10
    str = Cells(1, 1).Value
    var = Cells(1, 1).Value

    'Comparison for double
    Debug.Print dbl < "2"       '-> False
    Debug.Print dbl < "2"       '->False

    'Comparison for string
    Debug.Print str < "2"       '-> True
    Debug.Print str < 2         '->False

    'Comparison for variant
    Debug.Print TypeName(var)   '->Double
    Debug.Print var < "2"       '->True
    Debug.Print var < 2         '->False
    Debug.Print CDbl(var) < "2" '->False
End Sub
```

The behavior for double and string variables is as expected (if there are two strings then compare strings, if there is one numerical variable then convert the other to a number as well). The variant type behaves kind of weird though because although its type is displayed as `Double` it still is converted to a string when compared to a string. Of course if you compare two of these variables, they get treated as numbers again...

---

Conclusion: If you avoid to compare to variables that are explicit strings, you are good to go.